# Check uri is valid without causing it to download using HttpClient

Tags: c#, httpclient

How to Verify if the download uri is valid without causing client to download content?

Comment: Define "uri is valid"

Comment: Your answer should not be in the question if you are going to answer it yourself.

Comment: Actually, your answer should never be in the question. Your question should meet the same level of quality as we expect. See [ask] for that. Also see the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for more on self-answering.

Answer (score -2):

1. create client
2. Use client.GetAsync(uri, HttpComplettionOption) api
3. use ResponseHeadersRead

this will only check if the uri is valid without downloading actual content.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var downloadUri = new Uri("https://domainame/someblobcontent.zip");
Task<HttpResponseMessage> response = null;
try
 {
       using (response = client.GetAsync(downloadUri, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
            {
                if(response.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("uri is valid, got response code {0}", response.Result.StatusCode);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("uri is not valid, got response code {0}", response.Result.StatusCode);
                }
            }
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
      Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
  }
```

Comment: Huh? Is this supposed to be an answer to your question?

Comment: @DigiFriend You are allowed (even encouraged) to answer your own questions here on Stack Overflow. See the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for more. There are some rules; namely, the question and answer must be of the same level of quality as any others.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan - sure, but this looks like an exact copy of the question, hence my confusion.

Comment: @DigiFriend Yeah, this is arguably a poor example of what we're looking for in a self-answered question :).